# Usage of ssh-agent with signed SSH keys

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, ssh-agent

My ssh-agent doesn't want to store my credentials for Signed SSH key when connecting to a SSH server that use a SSH CA. I mean, each time i try to logon it ask me for the passphrase of the certified key.

It works if I use server without SSH CA.

I set up a CA for SSH on some Linux servers, as following :

- Create a CA keypair for test : `ssh-keygen -f myCA`
- Send the `myCA.pub` on the server and configure the sshd with the appropriate setting :  `TrustedUserCAKeys /etc/ssh/myCA.pub`
- Restart the server.
- Create a keypair for test : `ssh-keygen -f myKey`
- Sign the Key with CA : `ssh-keygen -s myCA -I user_username -n username -V +2w myKey.pub`

Anyone knows if it's possible ? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried ssh-copy-id and copy your IDs to remote server?

Comment: In this case, the advantages of having a CA for SSH is to not have to send my ID to the server. But I tried, in case of, and doesn't help.

Comment: It appears like you didn't load your key into ssh-agent with ssh-add after you created the certificate, or the ssh-agent environment variables are not in your ssh client's environment. It actually sounds like your key/ca/cert and remote setup is working perfectly, except it isn't going through your agent, it is using the identity on disk. Testing against ssh-agent from openssh 7.4, ssh-add automatically picks up cert files for private keys in the same directory and authenticates properly.